# How to Adjust the Thickness of a Line Segment Separator in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to add a line segment separator to the TOC and discovered that the following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\addtocontents{toc}{{\textbf{------------------}}}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\rule{1.5in}{.02mm}}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

However, I would like to make the separator thicker; and I figured that I would try this:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\rule{1.5in}{.02mm}}
```

But alas, it does not work (lots of error lines resulting).

Question: How may I adjust the thickness (and length expediently) of a line segment separator in the TOC? It seems like this should be a simple task, but I have not been able to figure out how.

Comment: No error for me... Also, I suggest using pt's as your thickness. Default for a thick line is 0.8pt, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @likethevegetable Thank you for the suggestion; but unfortunately, pts on my end still does not work.

Comment: It works for me too with the `\rule`, but maybe `\protect\rule` is needed with older versions of the LaTeX kernel (with mine, `\rule` is robust)? `\show\rule` would tell us more—or the error message.

Comment: @frougon Thank you very much. \protect\rule does the trick. My version of Latex is not current and this is a good remedy for users such as myself with out-of-date versions.  Thank you again.

Comment: @frougon Perhaps you will consider posting this as an answer. Unfortunately, I understand that I will not be able to upvote it with less than 25 reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Use `\protect\rule` instead of `\rule`, or update your TeX distribution.

## Long answer

`\addtocontents` uses TeX's `\write` primitve to write LaTeX code to the .toc file, and `\write` recursively expands tokens when the page it is on is shipped out (`\write` causes a *whatsit* node to be added to the current list TeX is assembling, so in the end, this node is on a well-defined page). This is necessary so that `\thepage` expands to the proper page number despite the fact that TeX doesn't know where a given character/box/whatsit/etc. of a paragaph will be before the paragraph has been *fully read* (this is because it optimizes *the set of all line breaks* in each paragraph).

So, this `\write` operation causes macros to be expanded, but there are macros that have been put there to be expanded later when the .toc file is read for typesetting the TOC, not when it is written. This is often the case for tests.

In your example, `\rule` uses `\@ifnextchar` to test for the presence of a `[`, i.e. to determine if the optional argument (specifying the amount by which the rule should be raised) has been provided. How does this work?

With some simplification (because `\@ifnextchar` skips space tokens while it looks for the next non-space token), `\@ifnextchar` uses `\futurelet` to set `\@let@token` to the next token in the input stream and to insert some macro that will test whether `\@let@token` is `\ifx`-equivalent to `[`. And this is where early expansion by `\write` makes it fail miserably: the `\futurelet` primitive can't do its work when TeX is only expanding tokens (which is the case when `\write` recursively expands its argument). `\futurelet` is *unexpandable*; its expansion is `\futurelet`. So, when the `\write` expands its argument, the `\futurelet` doesn't assign `\@let@token`, however the following test to see if `\@let@token` is `\ifx`-equivalent to `[` is by nature expandable. So, it gets expanded (the true or false branch is discarded depending on the current meaning of `\@let@token`, whatever it is), and the result (after all expandable stuff has been expanded) is what will be written to the .toc file. If no further error prevents the `\write` from being carried, this means that a choice will be made and the result carved in stone (the .toc file), but this choice won't be made in the proper way.

If the “wrong” code branch is taken, for instance if the remaining branch corresponds to the presence of an optional argument while there was none, macros in this branch are likely to cause errors early on, when `\write` expands them: for instance, one is likely to have a macro taking an argument delimited by `[`, which will cause an error if there is no `[` in the expected place (it could grab large parts of the document before finding a suitable `[`, causing further errors later on, or not find any before the end of file is reached).

That is a possible cause of error on the first LaTeX run. Errors are also possible during subsequent runs when the .toc file is read because of code written there by `\write` that was expanded too early.

In order to allow one to avoid this kind of problems, there are several techniques. First, let's note that `\addtocontents` doesn't use `\write` directly, but a wrapper macro called `\protected@write`. By default, this wrapper macro expands all expandable tokens immediately, except `\thepage`; also, tokens preceded by `\protect` are not expanded at all by `\protected@write` (`\protect\whatever` is written as `\protect \whatever` ).

With this in mind, here are the typical techniques used to prevent the problem you encountered:

- The `\rule` macro can be made *robust*. This is a special type of definition, done with `\DeclareRobustCommand`, that uses `\protect` behind the scenes so that the “real” code is only delivered during typesetting, not in `\protect`-aware expansion-only contexts such as within `\protected@write`, `\protected@edef` & Co. This is what recent versions of the LaTeX kernel have (a robust `\rule` macro); in this case, users in your situation don't encounter any problem.
- When `\rule` (or whatever fragile command is causing problems) is not robust, which was apparently the case for you, you can precede it with `\protect`, i.e.: use `\protect\rule` instead of `\rule`. This prevents expansion of `\rule` by the `\protected@write` used by `\addtocontents`, so the problematic `\@ifnextchar` is not even seen at this stage. The real code of `\rule` is expanded when the .toc file is read (`\protect` is then `\let`-equal to `\@typeset@protect`, which is normally `\let`-equal to `\relax`).
- The main other possibility would be to define `\rule` as a `\protected` macro using something like `\protected\def\rule...` (or `\NewDocumentCommand`, etc.). In this case, even `\write` wouldn't expand it—the `\protected@write` mechanism wouldn't be needed. But the `\protected` primitive isn't part of Knuth's TeX; it was added in e-TeX. I think the LaTeX team developped the `\DeclareRobustCommand` + `\protect` technique in the meantime, or maybe it was developped later but they still wanted LaTeX to be usable with Knuth's TeX at that time; so, the `\DeclareRobustCommand` + `\protect` technique stayed there and is still widely used in the LaTeX kernel, despite the fact that, AFAIK, current LaTeX requires the e-TeX extensions.

Note: AFAIK, all TeX engines in active development have the `\protected` primitive; I believe they implement most, if not all of e-TeX's extensions.